# Why does axis=0 make sort work for column vector, and why does it work for array as well?

Tags: arrays, numpy, sorting, axis

If I have a column vector and I want to sort its elements

```
array([[2.96745334],
       [3.29622333],
       [6.1303673 ],
       [6.28396456],
       [6.15874633]])
```

If I do `np.sort(z, axis=1)`, thus sort by column, the result is the same vector with no sort.

If I do `np.sort(z, axis=0)`, the vector is correctly sorted:

```
array([[2.96745334],
       [3.29622333],
       [6.1303673 ],
       [6.15874633],
       [6.28396456]])
```

Why does this happen, since `axis=0` should mean "sort by row" while `axis=1` means "sort by column"?

Moreover with `axis=0` also an array will be sorted

```
np.array([2, 1, 5, 4, 3])
np.sort(z, axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

So it seems very convenient to always use `axis=0` if you don't know if a row or column vector is coming. Is this correct?

Comment: look at the `shape`.  `axis=0` means the first, whether (6,1), (6,), or (6,3,2)

Comment: The row/column terminology fits 2d array.  It breaks down with 1d (or even 0d) arrays.  That's why `numpy` uses `axis` number instead.  It generalizes to all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your notion of what the `axis` argument means is not quite correct. Think of `np.sort(v, axis=n)` that we will sort along the `n`-th axis:

If we define a vector `v = np.array([[1],[5],[1],[2],[3],[5]])` of shape `(6, 1)` (what you call a "column vector"), and sort along `axis=0`, these 6 values will get sorted. If we instead sort it along `axis=1`, we have bascially sort six different lists of length 1, so the result will be the same.

By default (that is, without defining anything else), `np.sort` will sort along the *last* axis (by default `axis=-1`). So if you have an array of shape `(6,3,7,3,8)`, calling `np.sort` on it will sort a number of lists of length 8.

I hope this clears up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, a column array is made within the bracket. If you add a comma, the interpreter puts the rest of your input in the next row.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[2.96745334],
       [3.29622333],
       [6.1303673 ],
       [6.28396456],
       [6.15874633]])
print(arr.shape)
#result: (5, 1)    #An array with 5 row and 1 column

arr3 = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4]])
print(arr3.shape)
#result: (1, 4)    #An array with 1 row and 4 columns
```

But just to see it as a matrix as well:

```
arr2 = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4],
                 [7, 6, 8, 8],
                 [1, 6, 7, 7]])
print(arr2.shape)
#result: (3, 4)    # Three rows are defined by the commas between the brackets.
```